# PHP Documenting Code - How to use @package and @subpackage tags?

Tags: php, documentation, cakephp-2.0

I am confused about how to properly use the @package and @subpackage tags when documenting my PHP code.  If it's of any relevance, this is for CakePHP 2.x

How would I write the package tags for the classes located in the following directories within my application, for example:

```
app/Model/User.php

app/Model/Behavior/Sortable.php

app/Model/Behavior/Custom/Validator.php

...
```

And so on, with further subdirectories.  I am particularly unsure about classes that reside in deep subdirectories.

```
/**
 * @package ??
 * @subpackage ??
 */
class ValidatorBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's matter of agreement and convention. Cake uses like:

```
/*
 * @package App
 * @subpackage App.Model.Behavior
 * /

...
```

Comment: Actually, I just had a look at a core Cake 2.1 file and it seems to use just `@package Cake.Model.Behavior` with no subpackages specified.

Comment: Yes, till 2.0 version they was using subpackage and package. Currently package is replaced by subpackage as i mentioned it's a matter of convention.